# Supplementary problems on lattices From Schaum Series Boolean Algebra 3.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra, algebraic-logic

Find whether the following partially ordered sets are lattices, whether they have a zero and unit elements and whether they are complemented lattices:

(d) The set of all positive integers, partially ordered by $\leq$, where:
$z_{1}$ $\leq$ $z_{2}$ iff $z_{2}$ is an integral multiple of $z_{1}.$

I do not know exactly what is the meaning of supremum and infimum in our case but I feel it is a lattice. I do not see that it has either zero or unit element.

This question is sooo difficult for my imagination, Could anyone help me in it?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $n\ne1$, you have $1\le n$. For all primes numbers $p$, you have  $k\le p \Rightarrow k=1$. So certainly $1$ is your zero element and thus any two elements must have an infinium (which is actually their $\gcd$). And the supremum is no more than their product (and is actually their ${\rm lcm}$).

There is no greatest element so this is not a complemented lattice.

Comment: Moreover, it's not a *relatively* complemented lattice, as $2$ has no complement in the interval $[1,4]=\{1,2,4\}.$

Comment: @bof  what do mean by relatively complemented lattice ?

Comment: @MathLover https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_lattice